# Signing the app with Upload certificate of Google Play Sign

Tags: android

I created a sign key, used it to sign my apk, uploaded apk to PlayMarket. 
After loading Upload key I added it to my keystore by `keytool -importcert -file upload_cert.der -keystore mykeystore.jks` command. Now when I try to sign my apk with new "mykey" alias I get "Failed to read key mykey from store: trusted certificate entries are not password-protected" error.
Could you please help me how to solve this problem.
[image]

Comment: upload that image, what exactly you are getting

Comment: @AMANSINGH Uploaded

Comment: did you checked your password?

Comment: @AMANSINGH sure

Comment: yep I have the same problem, imported certificates doesn't reuire password. I don't know how to build apk with this certificate,  any progress?

Comment: @MichałSułek No, I use the same key which was used when I uploaded first ver of app(

Comment: @LeShChEnKoUa that's not a solution, because new methodology doesn't require keystore to don't share keystore any more. So using previous keystore has no sense

Comment: @MichałSułek Do you have a better solution?

Comment: @LeShChEnKoUa For this moment no, Android Studio / Gradle / apksigner isn't ready to generate apk using only certificate, we need to wait